# PHP if empty, or if isset, do this

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<p><? echo $langdata['oneprodpage_brand']; ?>:</strong> <? echo $thisproduct['brandname']; ?></p>
```

It brings out this:

> Brand name: {brand name}

if no brand is given it adds by default "Without brand" (all data is sotred in DB)

I want to do somthing like if php finds this value "without brand" then do smthing...

How can I make it?

I tried this

```
 <? if ($thisproduct['brandname'] == Without brand) { ?>
 <? } else { ?>
 <p><? echo $langdata['oneprodpage_brand']; ?>:</strong> <? echo $thisproduct['brandname']; ?></p>
 <? }; ?>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: just put double quotes around Without brand. like this : "Without brand"

Comment: off-topic: why do you have a closing `</strong>` tag without an matching opening tag?

Comment: Sorry, i just missed this out, but its not important...

Comment: please tell me you are not opening and closing your PHP on every line....

Comment: what does it means 'PHP if empty, or if isset, do this'?

Comment: sorry, then what do you want? I mean, whats your problem? I just cant understand it properly

Comment: Bhavik Shah - thankyou "" resolved the problem

Comment: This code should throw a parse error. http://codepad.org/f7M4fsnf . Why wouldn't you mention that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$withoutBrandNames = array('Without brand');
if (in_array($thisproduct['brandname'], $withoutBrandNames)) {
    $thisproduct['brandname'] = 'This product has no brand';
}
echo $thisproduct['brandname'];
```

Or, if you think as the comments suggest:

```
if (stristr($thisproduct['brandname'], 'Without brand') === false) {
    $thisproduct['brandname'] = 'This product has no brand';
}
echo $thisproduct['brandname'];
```

I used the case insensitive comparison function in case there was likelihood of case anomalies, the choice is of course your own.

PS: As the comments suggest you don't have to keep opening and closing your tags if they all contain code, you can even use short term syntax like this:

```
<?php if (statement): ?>
    <p> Some lovely HTML</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Some different lovely HTML</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hate curly braces in view files, in fact, I hate PHP in general in view files - but this seems necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot some quotes around Without brand, your code would be:

```
<? if ($thisproduct['brandname'] == "Without brand") { ?>
 <? } else { ?>
 <p><? echo $langdata['oneprodpage_brand']; ?>:</strong> <? echo $thisproduct['brandname']; ?></p>
 <? }; ?>
```

The code that you want to execute when it's Without brand should come after:

```
<? if ($thisproduct['brandname'] == "Without brand") { ?>
```

and before:

```
<? } else { ?>
```

But imo it's really not that readable your way, I would prefer:

```
<?php
    if ($thisproduct['brandname'] == "Without brand") {
        // Do something
    } else {
        echo "<p>". $langdata['oneprodpage_brand'] ."</strong>". $thisproduct['brandname'] ."</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: +1 for correctness, +200 for readability...